# MS Outlook replacement app. and how to install for a novice Linux user

Tags: evolution

I am new to Linux.  I need a replacement for Microsoft Outlook that is actually a contact mgmt app. including contacts, calendar, tasks and email.  Ideally it would import my Outlook.pst file.

Thunderbird came with Ubuntu but is not even close to sufficient.

Evolution looks good.  However, I do not know how to install it - or any other Linux application that does not have an installer.  Please help.

Comment: What I really want is a client application on my computer, not on the web.  I keep emails in folders on my computer and do not always have access to the internet.  I can, with a client, look up phones, addresses, birthdays etc. - not always convenient via the web.  Thanks.

Comment: When I stopped handling mail in outlook, I wanted to switch to `thunderbird`, but my mail PST folder covered ~15 years (using a lot more than just email syncing with a ipaq cell phone), and found `evolution` easier to import it. I've been using evolution every since.  It's installed with a `sudo apt install evolution`

Answer (score 1):

When I stopped handling mail in outlook, I wanted to switch to `thunderbird`, but my mail PST folder covered ~15 years (using a lot more than just email syncing with my then ipaq cell phone), and I found `evolution` easier to import it. I've been using evolution every since.

It's installed with a

```
sudo apt install evolution
```

or you can go to Ubuntu-Software, Synaptic, Aptitude, Muon, Software-Boutique or whatever software packaging tool/store came with your Ubuntu system, and search for evolution there & click the 'install' button. (*it may not appear in all, but usually you have two package options when one is not complete.  My Lubuntu came with Muon & `evolution` is there & listed as installed*)

Answer (score 0):

I use gmail in Linux (called from Firefox browser) and like it. This Super User answer sums up importing your outlook: [How can I import a .PST to GMail?](https://superuser.com/posts/738632/edit)

> Install Google Mail Migration for Outlook (GAMMO) from Google (free
>   tool). And just run it. It is pretty straight forward. It will import
>   all mails in your pst into your gmail account.
>
> [Google Apps Migration for Microsoft Outlook®](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/outlookmigration)